# MVC - Default Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a site where I would like to have dynamically added pages. Because of this, I would like to have a simpler URL. What I am aiming for is a URL like the following:

```
http://www.mysite.com/my-page-url
```

Rather than a URL like the following:

```
http://www.mysite.com/pageController/my-page-url
```

MVC URLs tend to work like this: `|url|/|controller|/|action|/|params|`

What I would like to do is have: `|url|/|params|`

For the above URL, if the values of params does not equal the name of a controller, then I would like to pass those params to PageContoller.ProcessDynamicPage.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what the question is here. Can you please rephrase or be more concise? Also, if you have done some work already, it would be preferable for you to share that work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what your default params are, you could create a [route constraint](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx)

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{Param1}",
        new { controller = "ProcessDynamicPage", action = "YourAction" },
        new {Param1= @"\d+" }
    );
```

This would work if your parameter is an integer.

If your default params are strings or something and you can't create a regex, or something that can't implement `IRouteConstraint` your best bet it to create a matching action for each of your controllers that way when it falls through the default you've already attempted to do the matching.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "YourController",
    "YourController\{Param1}",
    new { controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction" }
   }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "YourController2",
    "YourController2\{Param1}",
    new { controller = "YourController2", action = "YourAction" }
     }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{Param1}",
    new { controller = "ProcessDynamicPage", action = "YourAction" }          
);
```

If you have a lot of controllers, you should probably really look into how to create the constraint for what you're expecting.

Answer (score 2):

Using MVC's default routing scheme, `http://www.mysite.com/my-page-url` will go to the Index action in `my-page-url` controller. If you want to set the default controller and action, you can do so in your Global.asax.cs file it to something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{action}/{pageName}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "PageContoller", action = "ProcessDynamicPage", pageName = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

**Update**

If you need to support additional routes you can create them using the kind of approach that Mark Oreta has suggested. Have a look [at Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) and [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs).

Comment: Good idea. I'm afraid I didn't know about the new MVC approach when I added my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS 7 you need to look at Handler Mappings. You can specify a particular extension, e.g. *.action, to be handled by your default controller. I'm a bit rusty now, but I think it was basically the same idea in IIS 6. In my web.config file for my .Net 2.0 application I have the following section inside the system.webServer tag:

```
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="defaultAction" path="*.action"   
                verb="*" 
                type="SumikinIntercom.Web.Controller.Controller,SumikinIntercom.Web.Controller" 
                resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" allowPathInfo="true" />
        </handlers>
```

So any URL with the extension .action is handled by my default Controller class. Notice the awkward syntax. I had to specify the fully qualified class name (including the assembly name) followed by a comma then the fully qualified assembly name.

There may be irritating changes of syntax for more up-to-date versions of .Net so watch out for those.

Comment: @rhughes This answer may be a little out of date considering Zaid's more specific answer addressing MVC's special functionality, but I'll just leave it because it proved very useful for me in the past.